# How do I make the alter function/ assoc function return nil?

Tags: clojure

I have a really really huge hash table and whenever I try to alter the hash,  the entire hash is returned, which crashes my REPL. Is there a way I can ask Clojure to just set the value and return nil?

Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

`dorun` always returns `nil`:

```
(dorun (alter ...))
```

If all you want is to prevent the REPL from printing huge data structures, use `*print-level*` or `*print-length*`.

```
user> (set! *print-level* 2)
2
user> {:foo {:bar {:baz {:quux 1}}}}
{:foo {:bar #}}
user> (set! *print-length* 2)
2
user> (range 100)
(0 1 ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Clojures data types are immutable. Also they use shared structure so actually creating a new value is very very cheap for memory and performance. There are options to increase the memory available to the JVM like java -server. Also you can create Java objects which are mutable if you really need them.